# Reproducible executables. What controls the Entry Point Address?

Tags: c++, linux, linker

For regulatory reasons, I have to have the executable I submit be bit-for-bit identical to the executable the state agency produces when they compile my code. It's actually more than just the executable, it's the entire disk output image (this is a much more difficult problem than it sounds), but I think I'm only having issues with the executable at this point.

I have a dedicated Fedora Linux build box, and I have the same Fedora set up in a VM running on my dev box. The state agency also has a Fedora VM, installed identically to my local Fedora VM. The output on my build machine and my VM matches, but the state's is different. It's very close to identical but not quite.

I find that both executables have different Entry Point Addresses, and hence a lot of other addresses are different in the file in the readelf output.
One has 0x84548b0 for the address and the other has 0x8454860, so a difference of 0x50. That's explains why it's close to identical but not quite. Many of the binary difference I find are differences of 0x50.

So what is controlling where the linker decides to set the entry point address? What difference could there be between the two VM's that produce these differences? And most importantly, how to make this deterministic?

As a sort of follow up, here's what I'm doing to get the output to be identical, if anyone has any tips on anything else to do, I'd appreciate it.

The compiler has a whole slew of flags:

```
-pipe -pthread -g -ggdb -D__USE_LARGEFILE64 -D_REENTRANT -DTIXML_USE_STL -DFW_NEW_BUILD_SYS -DFW_BUILD_NEW_FRF -DWITH_PROGRESSIVE=1 -DFW_COPYRIGHT_YEAR=$(shell date '+%Y') -DRELEASE -DNDEBUG -O3 -Os -fgcse-sm -fgcse-las -fgcse-after-reload -fgcse-after-reload -funsafe-loop-optimizations -fomit-frame-pointer -D_DEBUG -D__DATE__="'Jan 9 2020'" -D__TIME__="'12:00:00'" -rdynamic -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -ffunction-sections
```

and linker flags:

```
-fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wl --gc-sections
```

Then to strip out differences I run:

```
objcopy --only-keep-debug Builds/Bin/Game Builds/Bin/GameSymbols
strip --strip-debug --strip-unneeded --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note --remove-section=.gnu.version --remove-section=.note.gnu.build-id Builds/Bin/Game
```

Comment: Using readelf, I figured out exactly where the differences were and it turns out glibc and friends were a slightly newer minor version in one vm. Now on to find out how that happened.. So the moral of the story is examine the elf structure to help find out differences between executables.